# Using generics to share a common method with multiple arguments

Tags: generics, java-8

I am finding that i have a method that is able to accept two types of List<> objects. For example:

```
public void foo(Long id) {};
```

The above function would be called on multiple objects each of whom have either an id of type Long or Integer. What's happening is that for objects that have their id defined as Long, this method call works just fine:

```
class Bar {Long id}
Bar test = new Bar(1L);
foo(bar.id);
```

But for objects that have an Integer id, I have to first convert the Integer to Long before using foo. I can of course have a new method that takes in a Integer but Id rather not do that. Any way to do this with generics?

Comment: Could your method be modified to handle other numeric types like `Double`, `Float`, etc?

Comment: Any reason for using `Long` and `Integer` rather than `long` and `int`? Since the use case of an *id* usually precludes `null`, I don’t see any, besides the desire to run into the problem you describe. As, with `long` and `int`, no explicit conversion is necessary…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't define a type that is an "OR" of two types.

However, you can accept `Number`, which includes both `Long` and `Integer` types, and use its `longValue()` method:

```
public void foo(Number number) {
    Long id = number.longValue();
    // rest of code stays the same
}
```

Comment: You can achieve the same by declaring the parameter as `long` and then boxing it into a `Long` within the method if really needed. That has the neat side effect of not allowing, e.g. `double` or `BigDecimal`, as input.